# Paypal REST api billing agreement Search for transactions

Tags: php, curl, paypal

For my project, I'm trying to use the REST api to process recurring payments. I've set up the billing agreement and everything is working fine, but I'm having problems trying to search for transactions.

I'm using curl in PHP.

This is my code :

```
$url =  "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-8E0VJL3DEL9N//transaction?start-date=2012-04-10&end-date=2014-11-18" ;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Authorization: Bearer A015zQG9wQ6uBkQE39DRk5eeBVqw67NFVx3ReErsG-80Qwg',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(empty($result))die(curl_error($curl)); // Retourne l'erreur
else
{   // Je récupère les infos renvoyés par le serveur
    $json = json_decode($result);
    // Récupération de l'adresse de la transaction
}
curl_close($curl);

// Fin de l'agreement
```

When I use the script, it gives me back this error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I don't know where my problem come from; I've tried a lot of different things, but nothing works and I still have the same response in `$result`.

Comment: Not sure about the reason, but have you tried using the official REST SDK for PayPal.https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

Also, you can checkout the samples provided here http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/index.html. They can all be executed by using the PayPal SDK.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like changing the url to:

`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-8E0VJL3DEL9N/transactions?start_date=2012-04-10&end_date=2014-11-18`

does the trick:

```
{
    "agreement_transaction_list": [
        {
            "payer_email": "",
            "payer_name": "Test Buyer",
            "status": "Created",
            "time_stamp": "2014-11-18T18:12:58Z",
            "time_zone": "GMT",
            "transaction_id": "I-8E0VJL3DEL9N",
            "transaction_type": "Recurring Payment"
        },
        {
            "payer_email": "",
            "payer_name": "Test Buyer",
            "status": "Suspended",
            "time_stamp": "2014-11-18T18:14:26Z",
            "time_zone": "GMT",
            "transaction_id": "I-8E0VJL3DEL9N",
            "transaction_type": "Recurring Payment"
        },
        {
            "payer_email": "",
            "payer_name": "Test Buyer",
            "status": "Reactivated",
            "time_stamp": "2014-11-18T18:16:20Z",
            "time_zone": "GMT",
            "transaction_id": "I-8E0VJL3DEL9N",
            "transaction_type": "Recurring Payment"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error while trying to execute a payment. Turned out I was posting to the wrong URL. **Check the URL is correct**.

ie :

`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-8E0VJL3DEL9N//transactions`

instead of :

`https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/I-8E0VJL3DEL9N//transaction` (+s)